# Can't save files now from YouTube

Tags: youtube

Am I right that some recent change has now prevented this?
Is this a worldwide change?

Comment: What are you trying exactly to save the videos?

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about downloading your own video, you can do so from the video manager:
[image: How to Download Your Own Video.]

If you want to download other people's videos you can use a 3rd party site, like the one below.

Normal URL:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1q7Leq6wqxA
```

How you would modify it for downloading:

```
http://www.keepyoutube.com/watch?v=1q7Leq6wqxA
```

Hope that is what your question was asking about!

Comment: The keepyoutube.com site runs a Java app and reports the certificate is unknown - is it safe?

Comment: Yes it is. I have been using it for quite some time and have been fine. No virus threats at all.

Answer (score 1):

I use [FlashGot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashgot/) + [DownThemAll!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) add-ons on Firefox to download videos. Just tested now to see that it is working.

I hope that's what you want.

Comment: But with what you suggest it's only for firefox. This means it only applies if he is using FireFox which he may not be.